# Increasing performance in custom sorting of a string array

Tags: c#, arrays, performance, algorithm, sorting

I am trying to find an efficient way to sort an array of strings based on a numeric value within each string element of the array. I am currently using the Array.Sort(array, customComparer) static method (quick sort), with my custom comparer class (sorting in descending order) being:

```
class StringComparer : IComparer<string>
{
    public int Compare(string a, string b)
    {
        string s1 = a;
        string s2 = b;

        Match matchA = Regex.Match(s1, @"\d+$");
        Match matchB = Regex.Match(s2, @"\d+$");

        long numberA = long.Parse(matchA.Value);
        long numberB = long.Parse(matchB.Value);

        if (numberB - numberA < 0)
        {
            return -1;
        }
        else 
        {
            return 1;
        }
    }
}
```

This works very well, but sometimes it takes too much time to sort, with an array of 100 000 strings taking more than a minute on a 2.4Ghz processor. I wonder if there is a more efficient way to accomplish the same. For example, implementing a different sorting algorithm or taking another approach like using a dictionary and sorting on the value (the value being the numeric part of the string). Any suggestions? Thanks in advance!

Comment: "using a dictionary and sorting on the value" sounds very promising. Have you tried it?

Comment: you could try [Radix Sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radix_sort), which targets this kind of sorts: "sorts data with integer keys by grouping keys by the individual digits which share the same significant position and value"

Comment: @Luiggi Mendoza: The sorting algorithm is not the bottleneck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you're needlessly parsing the same string over and over (both matching with the regular expression and then parsing the matches). Instead, encapsulate what you have into a custom type so that you only have to parse once.

```
public class FooString {
    private readonly string foo;
    private readonly long bar;

    public FooString(string foo) {
        this.foo = foo;
        Match match = Regex.Match(foo, @"\d+$");
        this.bar = Int64.Parse(match.Value);
    }

    public string Foo { get { return this.foo; } }
    public long Bar { get { return this.bar; } }
}
```

I'd even add a `Contract.Requires` to this class that says that `foo` must satisfy the regular expression.

Second, you have an `IComparer<T>` that dies on certain values of `T` (in your case, `string`s that don't match the regular expression and can't be parsed to a `long`). This is generally a bad idea.

So, make the comparer for `FooString`:

```
public FooStringComparer : IComparer<FooString> {
    public int Compare(FooString a, FooString b) {
        Contract.Requires(a != null);
        Contract.Requires(b != null);
        return a.Bar.CompareTo(b.Bar);
    }
}
```

Now, your sorting will be blazingly fast because you've stopped parsing the same string over and over.

Comment: Your approach is great! I tested with 100 000 elements and the sorting process took just a few seconds! This used to take more than a minute before! The only part that takes time now is initiating the array of CustomStrings which I do with 'CustomString[] arrayOfCustomStrings = new CustomString[matchCollection.Count];' this takes about 12 seconds to create the array but after that it gets sorted in a matter of a second or two. Just for the record, I had to change 'this.bar = Int64.Parse(match)' to 'this.bar = Int64.Parse(match.value);' This was very helpful. Thanks Jason!

Answer (score 5):

You're parsing the value for each comparison. I would suggest you parse *once*, to get a string/long pair, sort that, and then extract the string part afterwards.

Note that your existing code has a bug: it will *never* return 0, for two strings comparing as equal.

Here's an alternative approach using LINQ (which isn't in-place sorting, but is simple.)

```
var sorted = unsorted.OrderBy(x => long.Parse(Regex.Match(x, @"\d+$").Value));
                     .ToList();
```

(`OrderBy` projects once to get the keys, then compares keys.)

Comment: LINQ sounds good and I will test it. However, I am targeting .NET 2.0. Thanks!

Comment: @cake: You can use LINQBridge or something similar to use LINQ to Objects in .NET 2.0. (In future, if you're going to require a very old version of the framework, it would be helpful to say so in the question.) You can basically do the same thing though: work out all the keys once, and then sort with those.

Comment: Sorry about forgetting to mention the required version. I opted for a custom string class which compares really fast as suggested by Jason. I was not aware of LinqBridge but I will definitely look into it and compare. Thanks!

Comment: just tried LinqBridge and it worked good but there is still too much parsing and regex so the code is still slow. Thanks for mentioning LinqBridge, I used it somewhere else.

Comment: @cake: Well that's only going to be doing the parsing and regex once per value... so it shouldn't be any slower than the accepted answer.

Answer (score 3):

You are now performing the Regexes O(n log n) times.

Consider looping once over all strings, extracting the numerical value and adding it to a `SortedDictionary<long, string>`

This requires only O(n) executions of the Reg expression. The rest of the sorting should be comparable.

Answer (score 1):

Create the `Regex` only once with the `Compiled` option. This will increase the speed.

```
class StringComparer : IComparer<string>
{
    private static Regex _regex = new Regex(@"\d+$", RegexOptions.Compiled);

    public int Compare(string a, string b)
    {
        long numberA = Int64.Parse(_regex.Match(a).Value);
        long numberB = Int64.Parse(_regex.Match(b).Value);
        return numberA.CompareTo(numberB);
    }
}
```

Comment: By default, Regex expressions are compiled and cached. This should not make any difference.

Comment: @HenkHolterman: The OP uses `Regex.Match(s1, @"\d+$");` which will not be compiled. However, you are right by pointing out the regex will be compiled by default, when the pattern is passed in the constructor.

Comment: See: [As a result, regular expression pattern-matching methods offer comparable performance for static and instance methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

Comment: Ok, I see. I did not know that the static methods compile and cache the expressions.